# Alphabetically Sort a Sentence in Java

Tags: java, list

I finished my program which alphabetizes words, but I am trying to get to alphabetize an entire sentence...or paragraph...or story. Pretty much anything you throw at it.

So far this is my code:

```
package Main;


import java.io.Console;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ABCs2
{    
    public static final void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        char reply;
        String r1, r2, r3, r4;
        String s1;

        System.out.print("Alphabetize words: W | or press S to sort sentence..");
        reply = a.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
        if (reply == 'W' || reply == 'w')
        {
            System.out.print("Enter word 1");
            r1 = a.next();

            System.out.print("Enter word 2");
            r2 = a.next();

            System.out.print("Enter word 3");
            r3 = a.next();

            System.out.print("Enter word 4");
            r4 = a.next();

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(r1);
            list.add(r2);
            list.add(r3);
            list.add(r4);

            System.out.println("Alphabetizing...");
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            java.util.Collections.sort(list);

            System.out.println("Your alphabetized list:");
            System.out.println(list);

            for (String str : list)
            {
                System.out.println(str);
            }
        }

        if (reply == 'S' || reply == 's')
        {
            System.out.println("Enter sentence..."); 
            s1 = a.next();

            List<String> slist = new ArrayList<>();
            slist.add(s1);
            System.out.println("Alphabetizing...");
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();        
            }

            java.util.Collections.sort(slist); 

            System.out.println("Your alphabetized sentence...");
            System.out.println(slist);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to output an entire alphabetized sentence, but instead I just get the first word. Should I even need to use a list? Thanks! I don't need it completely answered, just a step in the right direction!

Answer (score 3):

```
    {;{}
```

??
I'm not sure the purpose of this line in your code above.

But regarding your problem, Scanner's `next()` method will get the next *token* in a String, and that's it. In other words it will get the first word in your String up to the next whitespace character. You will want to get the whole String with `nextLine()` and then split it apart with String's `split()` method and then sort the String array returned.

Your question shows the importance of debugging similar problems. You'd have identified the problem if you printed your String before you added it to the list. Try to sprinkle your code with temporary test println statements (or use a debugger) to try to identify your errors, and then remove the println's from the final code. The more debugging attempts that you do, the better you'll get at it.

In other words, you would try something like this:

```
System.out.println("Enter sentence..."); 
s1 = a.next();

System.out.println("Debug, s1 = " + s1);  // TODO: delete this line

List<String> slist = new ArrayList<>();
slist.add(s1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this with a app to sort books by title:
I know that you're not storing books, this is to demonstrate how to order String objects of any length.

create a class or inner class of the object type that you want to sort, for me it was books:

```
class Book {
   String title;
   public Book(String t) {
       title = t;
   }
```

You can also override toString() to change the way that it is displayed(ie indentations, next line calls, etc) in the class of the objects that store the strings.

create an inner class to your main class that looks something like this:

```
class BookCompare implements Comparator<Book> {
    public int compare(Book one, Book two) {
        return one.title.compareTo(two.title);
    }
}
```

Instantiate the class that implements the Comparator.

You can now use something like LinkedList to store instances of book:

```
LinkedList<Book> bookList = new LinkedList <>();
```

Add your sentences to the linked list as such:

```
bookList.add(new Book("Whatever you want the string to be"));
```

Now use the Collections.sort() method with the Comparing class to order them alphabetically:

```
Collections.sort(bookList,instanceOfCompareClass);
```

When the objects are displayed, it will be the way that you defined in the toString() method and they will be in alphabetical order.

I know that you're not ordering books, but this was an example of using Comparator with code that I have already written. Hope this was helpful to you. Best of luck.

Additional Note: You will need to import java.util.* to use the Comparator interface.